# Can I use pouchdb to store images

Tags: pouchdb, cloudant

I'm looking for an easy way to handle offline/online situation in a mobile app. It seems that pouchdb is an interesting option to use pairing with cloudant. But is it a good idea to use it to store binary data like images ? Or is there a limitation with storage size or any other ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PouchDB supports attachments to documents, just as CouchDB does. It should therefore be possible to attach a local file to the PouchDB database and then sync the data to a remote CouchDB/Cloudant database.

This is an excellent solution for offline-first storage; the storage limits you would run into depend on the browser being used. [See PouchDB's FAQ page for the list of browsers and storage limits](http://pouchdb.com/faq.html).

If you're worried about the performance issues of having too many or too large attachments in your database, you could take a hybrid approach and use attachments to initially save the attached object, but use a script server side to take the attachment, copy to object storage and then modify the document to include the URL of attachment's new home. You can then delete the attachment itself to reduce storage space.

Answer (score 0):

To store image or files

```
<input type="file">
```

js

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('change', function () {
  var file = input.files[0]; // file is a Blob

  db.put({
    _id: 'mydoc',
    _attachments: {
      filename: {
        type: file.type,
        data: file
      }
    }
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

http://bl.ocks.org/ntwcklng/f57b03c15e91c25e2cb5